# Database "sample" does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a create a database using the following query:

```
create database sample;
```

but when I try to access the database Psequel GUI or my nodejs server, I keep getting this error:

> database "sample" does not exist

Database sample is clearly available as shown below.

```
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 reveal    | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 revealdb  | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 sampl     | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 sample    | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Comment: Can be you login with user not exist.

Comment: Tried: `su postgres -c "psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE USER username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password'\""`   and   
`su postgres -c "psql -U postgres -c \"CREATE DATABASE sample WITH OWNER=username ENCODING='UTF8'\""`

Comment: Or: `sample` is specified name in Postgres. You can't create the database with this name. Should be another name like `samplepostgres`

Comment: recheck refresh object tree. recheck connection address.

Comment: Maybe it helps to set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` and `log_connections = on`, try again and then see what you get in the PostgreSQL log. Maybe that gives you a clue what is going on.

Comment: `... but when I try to access the database Psequel GUI or my nodejs server ...` How ?

Comment: I don't know what was happening, but I uninstalled everything and just installed the postgres app for mac, it did everything automatically.